# Difference in UNIX timestamp conversion between Hive And BQ for very old dates (year 1400)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, hive, database-migration

Anyone have any idea why I might be getting different results for two identical UNIX times in BQ and Hive?

Hive:

`select FROM_UNIXTIME(-17429212800)`

returns
`1417-09-01 00:00:00`

BQ:

`select TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(-17429212800)`

returns
`1417-09-10 00:00:00`

---

---

But if I use the same functions on earlier UNIX times then the results are the same

Hive:

`select FROM_UNIXTIME(-10429212800)`

returns
`1639-07-06 12:26:40`

BQ:

`select TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(-10429212800)`

returns
`1639-07-06 12:26:40`

Comment: Ten days difference? 15:th century? It's a [Julian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar) versus [Gregorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) calendar thing.

Comment: Also please note that "Unix" timestamps doesn't go further back than midnight on January 1, 1970. It also doesn't go negative.

Comment: Some systems do support negative values, however officially, only positive values are supported. Report your issue to the Hive development team. https://hive.apache.org/community/issuetracking/

Comment: Nah it turns out its the Gregorian calendar reform (as mentioned by Some programmer dude), the gap in days for Hive happens where the reform occurs.